# Android Jackson Mapping exception

Tags: java, android, jackson

I am calling an API and as a result I am able to get Json response. In this json I have one parameter **e.g.** `manufacturer` in which I am expecting to have an object of type `Manufacturer` (my custom class), but some time I am getting String from same named parameter into the API, due to this, I am able to get following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.response.Manufacturer] from String value ('59438a9f2e4ab8c26656fcfd'); no single-String constructor/factory.
```

Api response which I am getting is like:

```
{"manufacturer" : "59438a9f2e4ab8c26656fcfd"}
```

and sometime this response come like

```
{"manufacturer" : {"name":"Manufacturer Name"}}
```

My Manufacturer class is like

```
class Manufacturer {
 @JsonProperty("name")
 private String name;
  // getter and setter for this with @JsonProperty("name");
 }
```

I have searched alot for this over google and not able to find any Solution. Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a constructor with a `String` argument in `Manufacturer` that Jackson will use when it sees a string field in JSON and has to create `Manufacturer` field in the Java class:

```
class Manufacturer {
    Manufacturer(String id) {
        this.name = // initialize as you see fit
    }

    Manufacturer() {} // compiler no longer creates this
```